# Unexpected distortion of Font Awesome Icons placed inside CSS created Hexagon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, font-awesome, css-shapes

I'm attempting to add social media icons using the Font-awesome **i tag with fa class**  to a Hexagon background. The social media icons should all sit next to each other inside hexagon backgrounds and change background color on hover.  However the problems I'm getting are as following:

**UPDATE** The fiddle is almost right, we just need to be able to make the shpae look like a Hexagon https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/4/

[image]

> **Problems:**
>
> **1.** The social media icons are warped by the hexagon
>
> **2.** The hexagon now won't change background color on hover
>
> **3.** The social media icons should be more img-responsive

https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/

**HTML**

```
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <div class="row">


              <div class="social">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a class="hexagon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></i> </a> </li>
                    <li><a class="hexagon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i> </a> </li>
                      <li><a class="hexagon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i> </a> </li>
                    <li><a class="hexagon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-yelp"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a class="hexagon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                      <div class="social">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></i> </a> </li>
                    <li><a class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i> </a> </li>
                      <li><a class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i> </a> </li>
                    <li><a class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-yelp"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }



    .hexagon {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 8.5%;
        padding: 16%;
        transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866); /* .866 = sqrt(3)/2 */
    }
    .hexagon:before{
        display: block;
        position: absolute; /* 86.6% = (sqrt(3)/2)*100% = .866*100% */
        top: 6.7%; right: 0; bottom: 6.7%; left: 0; /* 6.7% = (100% -86.6%)/2 */
        transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg); /* 1.155 = 2/sqrt(3) */
        background-color: rgba(30,144,255,.56);
        background-size: cover;
        content: '';
    }


        .social {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .social ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .social ul li {
        margin: 5px;
        list-style: none outside none;
        display: inline-block;
    }


        .social i {
        width:80px;
        height: 80px;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #333;
        font-size: 42px;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top: 25px;

        transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    }

    .social i:hover {

        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    }

        .social .fa-facebook:hover { /* round facebook icon*/
        background: #4060A5;
    }

    .social .fa-twitter:hover { /* round twitter icon*/
        background: #00ABE3;
    }

    .social .fa-yelp:hover { /* round google plus icon*/
        background: #e64522;
    }


    .social .fa-linkedin:hover { /* round linkedin icon*/
        background: #0094BC;
    }


    .social .fa-instagram:hover { /* round instagram icon*/
        background: #375989;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the hexagon i scaleX to 2.4 to get the desired hexagon shape I was looking for.

```
.hexagon i {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) skewY(0) scaleX(2.4);
}
```

This is the full working css:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }



.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 8.5%;
    padding: 16%;
    transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866); /* .866 = sqrt(3)/2 */
}
.hexagon:before{
    display: block;
    position: absolute; /* 86.6% = (sqrt(3)/2)*100% = .866*100% */
    top: 6.7%; right: 0; bottom: 6.7%; left: 0; /* 6.7% = (100% -86.6%)/2 */
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg); /* 1.155 = 2/sqrt(3) */
    /* background-color: rgba(30,144,255,.56); */
    background-size: cover;
    content: '';
}


    .social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.social ul li {
    margin: 5px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: inline-block;
}


    .social i {
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
    font-size: 42px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 25px;

    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.social i:hover {

    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

    .social .fa-facebook:hover { /* round facebook icon*/
    background: #4060A5;
}

.social .fa-twitter:hover { /* round twitter icon*/
    background: #00ABE3;
}

.social .fa-yelp:hover { /* round google plus icon*/
    background: #e64522;
}


.social .fa-linkedin:hover { /* round linkedin icon*/
    background: #0094BC;
}


.social .fa-instagram:hover { /* round instagram icon*/
    background: #375989;
}

.hexagon i {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) skewY(0) scaleX(2.4);
}
```

Thanks to Mike Barwick who helped me figure out most of the answer. Thanks to his help I was able to solve my problem.

This is the working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/5/

Answer (score 1):

You're transforming the child elements - and shouldn't be. Just revert the icons back - like so (but make sure this is ***after*** .hexagon:after):

```
.hexagon i {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) skewY(0) scaleX(1.866);
}
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/4/

If you're unable to play around with the scales and CSS to fit your needs, maybe you can use a library like this. Looks to be exactly what you want.

http://ninodezign.com/css3-hexagon-buttons/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/2/ How can I fill the entire Hexagon? It still looks like a square

Comment: Top row is hexagon...unless I'm missing something!?

Comment: Put `.hexagon i` AFTER hexagon stuff obviously. After the hexagon:after ;)

Comment: Check my fiddle in answer.

Comment: When you hover on the hexagon, it displays a square in a different color. The hexagon should fill up in it's entirety on hover and change color

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing - at all. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/4/

Comment: Hit "run" once it loads. jsfiddle is not loading `transform` content properly on page load.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/onkkdef6/4/ This fiddle is almost perfect, but it needs to be a hexagon shape

Comment: I'm seeing hexagons on the first row....screenshot what you see and mean..

Comment: Check the updated image, the top row should look like a hexagon, and when you hover over it, it should change color to fill up the entire hexagon. The fiddle you updated changed the shape of the hexagon

Comment: Not sure man. Check updated answer. Gave you an alternative library you might want to use instead.

Comment: Ok, I added a picture with the proper explanation of the shape I want to achieve. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I will have to figure out how to play with the transform and scale. Yes, I'm aware of that tutorial, however the problem is still how to rotate hexagon to look like the above picture